# Handle an incoming POST in Drupal (not a form, an incoming external request)

Tags: services

I'm trying to get a handle on the best way to handle [Mandrill incoming webhook requests](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/22092308-What-is-the-format-of-inbound-email-webhooks-), which are externally defined and not in a format that would normally be handled by the Services module or other API handlers I'm familiar with in Drupal. This is *not* a form, not not appropriate for the Form API. All I really know to do is to set up a menu router entry with hook_menu() and then process the $_POST. But it seems like there ought to be a better way.

It seems like most analogs of this are GET requests (like the Paypal IPN), which are a little more straightforward.

Suggestions?

BTW: The idea here is to have Mandrill handle incoming email and hit the Drupal site with a webhook request with the information from the incoming email already parsed out, so the Drupal site can take action, like posting a private message or replying to a comment thread.

Comment: I think an entry in `hook_menu` will be necessary in any case, unless the [Mandrill](https://drupal.org/project/mandrill) module handles that for you.

Comment: I don't believe the mandrill module handles this kind of thing yet but it would be a great feature request for the mandrill module to handle the menu item and then provide hooks for other modules to hook in and do something with the post. Rules integration could also be added and would be great.